# Remote test using jmeter triggers Connection refused error

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmeter, load-testing

I followed this step for configuration http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

- The 2 machines are on same subnet.
- They can ping each other
- Windows firewall is turned off

When I execute remote start its give a "Connection refused" exception.

error log

```
2011/12/07 13:39:37 ERROR - jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart: Failed to initialise remote engine java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 198.168.137.4; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.getEngine(ClientJMeterEngine.java:56)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.<init>(ClientJMeterEngine.java:69)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doRemoteInit(RemoteStart.java:176)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:79)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:82)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:42)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:61)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is resolve

my computer is connected to the internet and when i start jmeter-server its start on public ip.

my ip is 192.168.137.1 but some how its start on my public ip when i check on google with my public ip is same

i stop internet and start jmeter-serrver again its working

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check whether your RMI port on your other machine(s) is closed? jMeter uses 1099 by default.
Use cmd and type:

```
telnet [ip-address] 1099
```

You, of course, started the jMeter server on all machines, right?